# basic constructor with vector : Inappropriate default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

Here is the code to demonstrate the classic problem

```
class A
{
   public:
      A(int){}
};

class B
{
   vector<A> va; //Error no default constructor available
public:
   B(vector<A>v):va(v)
   {}
};
```

The error is no default constructor available. I don't need default constructor for class A, so don't write it.

Comment: Works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1b4f08bce932a20), problem with your compiler/standard library? Or is it triggered in the code you are *not* showing us?

Comment: I use compiler in VS2013

Comment: [This works](http://ideone.com/Gl9A0k) back to gcc 4.3.2, and I confirmed the same code works back to VS2010-SP1, so double-check the toolchain you have setup for your project. that `vector` is `std::vector`, *right* ? A full-on [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help considerably.

Answer (score -1):

Adding a trivial constructor for A will work for you

```
class A
{
   public:
      A(int) {}
      A() {}
};
```

Comment: @DanielFrey when you have your custom ctor. compiler won't generate the default ctor for you

Comment: That has nothing to do with the fact that the standard does not require a default ctor for `A` if you want to have a `std::vector<A>`. See the linked example in my comment on the question. It works for a lot of modern compilers (GCC, Clang, seemingly even VS).

Comment: how do you explain it doesn't work in VS2013, so maybe it's unspecified in standard. edited my answer a little bit.

Comment: Have you read the comment from @WhozCraig? It works with VS2013, even older versions. And I assure you it is standardized. The explanation is in the code the OP is not showing us (where he probably uses the vector in a way which then does require a default ctor), or in a totally broken toolchain.

Comment: @XiaotianPei I explain it because the OP isn't showing us all the code. Ex: If the vector is constructed with count-only specification (`vec(n);`) then `T` must support default construction. If constructed with count-value specification then `T` (`vec(n,A(0));`) then `T` must be copy-insertable. Wanna guess which one the OP is failing on (and *still* keeping secret from us)?

Comment: @WhozCraig Why will the code fail on the second case? btw, the code already use copy-constructor.

Comment: It will fail to compile if you utilize *any* member of `std::vector<>` the requires default-construction. Another ex:. `resize(size_t n)`  vs. `resize(size_t n,const T&)`. I surmise the OP is using one of those mentioned (didn't have time to list them all out, but those are common).

Comment: @WhozCraig that is not I'm asking. you said it may fail on second case which require copy-insertable. Are you implying copy-insertable require default-construtible?

Comment: No, I'm saying it is failing on the first case. If you declare `std::vector<Type> vec(n);` and `Type` is not default-constructible (or trivially constructible)  it is going to puke, plain and simple. The class doesn't need to be default-constructible to be copy-insertable. The same vector, but initialized as `std::vector<Type> vec(n,Type(args));` will succeed, and Type  need not support default-construction. [Fails](http://ideone.com/605O2O) vs [Works](http://ideone.com/NjBmBs). But again, *we don't have the OP's code*; the little we did get is not sufficient for their claim this won't work.